# Slow std::vector vs [] in C++ - Why?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, stdvector

I am a bit rusty with C++ - having used it 20 years ago.  I am trying to understand why std::vector is so much slower than native arrays in the following code.  Can anyone explain it to me?  I would much prefer using the standard libraries but not at the cost of this performance penalty:

Vector:

```c++
const int grid_e_rows = 50;
const int grid_e_cols = 50;

int H(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &sigma) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < grid_e_rows; ++r) {
        int r2 = (r + 1) % grid_e_rows;
        for (int c = 0; c < grid_e_cols; ++c) {
            int c2 = (c + 1) % grid_e_cols;

            h += 1 * sigma[r][c] * sigma[r][c2] + 1 * sigma[r][c] * sigma[r2][c];
        }
    }

    return -h;
}


int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::vector<std::vector<int>> sigma_a(grid_e_rows, std::vector<int>(grid_e_cols));
    for (int i=0;i<600000;i++)
        H(sigma_a);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Calculation completed in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count()
              << " seconds";

 return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Calculation completed in 23 seconds
```

Array:

```c++
const int grid_e_rows = 50;
const int grid_e_cols = 50;
typedef int (*Sigma)[grid_e_rows][grid_e_cols];

int H(Sigma sigma) {
    int h = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < grid_e_rows; ++r) {
        int r2 = (r + 1) % grid_e_rows;
        for (int c = 0; c < grid_e_cols; ++c) {
            int c2 = (c + 1) % grid_e_cols;

            h += 1 * (*sigma)[r][c] * (*sigma)[r][c2] + 1 * (*sigma)[r][c] * (*sigma)[r2][c];
        }
    }

    return -h;
}

int main() {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    int sigma_a[grid_e_rows][grid_e_cols];
    for (int i=0;i<600000;i++)
        H(&sigma_a);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Calculation completed in " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count()
              << " seconds";

 return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
Calculation completed in 6 seconds
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How did you compile these programs?

Comment: Exactly the same.  "/.../JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/202.7660.37/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/bin/cmake" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /.../C++/ising

Comment: Try a Release build (`-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`). Also, it's definitely worth noting that the vector code requires two array lookups, whereas the array only requires a single lookup (as the data is stored contiguously in the latter case).

Comment: Also try compiling with optimization (compiler flag -O3). That will probably make the runtimes more reasonable.

Comment: Include exact compiler command line.  When profiling, do something with the output outside the timed zone (or the proper optimizarion is "don't do it"). Profile setup seperately than execution.  Finally, vector solution is doing crazy stupid copying, and includes initializing data, and is a "jagged" array; array solution is a packed array, and uses uninitialized data.  But probably you profiled a debug build; in release, a compiler would skip the function if it could figure out it is pure and has the result discarded.

Comment: @Telescope , I would advise against using -O3, as it leads to code becoming more unstable. I would recommend using -O2, as it offers the most optimization with the least instability.

Comment: @Jake -O3 should be perfectly fine. Problems ("instability") that occur under heavy optimization are often indicators of Undefined Behavior in the code.

Comment: @nneonneo your answer seems to be the correct one.  Switching to release mode changed my results a lot.  However it is still 2.9 times slower than array.  Does that seem reasonable?

Comment: If you want to make the code similar change the 2D array to a 1D array of pointers to malloced 1D arrays (one for each row).  The results will then be similarly slow.

Comment: Yes, it's still reasonable. A nested vector behaves the same as indexing an array of arrays (`int *arr[grid_e_rows]`, where each pointer points to an array of integers). This is double indirection, and it will hurt your performance. One approach to mitigate this would be to use a `vector<int>` of size `grid_e_rows * grid_e_cols` and do the indexing manually - this will probably be faster.

Comment: If you know you'll always need a fixed-size array, try using `std::array` and you can recover some of the benefits of contiguous non-jagged access patterns. Example: `using Sigma = std::array<std::array<int, 50>, 50>;`. Those can also be used like any other STL container and can be passed around by value or reference, unlike plain arrays.

Comment: @Telescope I think a good optimizer would simply print "Calculation completed in 0 seconds" since H has no observable side effects. Or do I miss something? This is a common problem with trivial benchmarks.

Comment: @Telescope In fact, it could be a reasonable question here just why it doesn't optimize the calls away, at -O3. Curious whether it would if H were void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not compiling with optimizations.

Compare:

- [With `vector` of `vector`](https://tio.run/##jZLRToMwFIbveYqTGU0RZ7YZvQDGjTfe@QDLQppDB42sXdqyxRhfXWzL2GBGYy8oPefv17/nFHe7aYnYXnGBdVMwSLnURjG6zYJzbM/QSDWMYKWkkFnQohTaABcGSsWLnOVKHjQs4XGWBD9yKOs@F7jwC9GmiOMOnw7/bTbL4EbzcktD@AjAjr2sqeE188TKcizGxTdSAXEx5WN2SodmEogi1TPc8NKF1RIFEcxDuB7JT7oTFzsunrnuIo6LQ27PRs/GC7bfEozEFURLmMMt@Guu1HqF69FqsXaQ3wQLtzzb/Qy6r58UM40SMK2SwEZ8sbeUC9L7pY2RoA1Vxnr1he86GsfaMFq851hLfItjIQ8kPNr@u1feVE7JoJR3cCkjg2KE4UX7@HKW8PRp5kbCoyg8Xc2@k45@3OLdM1H8y/vJOsrGQJrC5JnW2Li3JAWg3O5qZlhhWwcTlx4Ri0Z5XY5Um3R8GLPvu9AZcUamXTHDe3uIMCQc9Rn8qXDcMHHlPPZn5trTtl@4qWmp2@nrwzc)
- [With array](https://tio.run/##jZI9b8MgEIZ3fsUpVSscK1Waqh1sJ0uXbh06RpaFDpKgOhABblRV@et1AefLqRSVAaS79557OcDNZrREbG@kwrrhAgqprTOCrWfkFMOV0UrPSItaWQdSOVgayStRGb21MIWncU7@5FDXh5z72gguFjFLh@9yuWbJ/AxRzs9qypyQIHylUQg2yuGbgF@fumZO1iKiVh7v6SG@0AZoiJkY80dx7jGHNDUHRlhROvFaaiCFhwRue/Kj7sjFjosnbvAauHjOPbAxsvGCHUtIT7yCdAoPMPRz6S46N@Ucy8vApAyo67JJiJys70i3x8MI1xgFo1VOdt1410wqerDOGqfBOmact20dz7LuzbPMOsH4V4W1xo8sU3pLk/0NAiS2rti1t@xNUU7HuSyex2HlMk2To9tXereHJfnJklD8X4ZCQafSjYOigMELq7EJf0UrQL3e1MIJ7j3DIKR7RN6YqKuQWVf0mwn/rbmd0WBk1E0oufdNlKNJ7x0hdoV9wSDMaD/zcRh52/7gomZL247eHn8B)

---

To give you a small taste of what the optimizer might be doing for you, consider the following modification to your `H()` function for the `vector` of `vector` case.

```
int H(std::vector<std::vector<int>> &arg) {
    int h = 0;
    auto sigma = arg.data();
    for (int r = 0; r < grid_e_rows; ++r) {
        int r2 = (r + 1) % grid_e_rows;
        auto sr = sigma[r].data();
        auto sr2 = sigma[r2].data();
        for (int c = 0; c < grid_e_cols; ++c) {
            int c2 = (c + 1) % grid_e_cols;
            h += 1 * sr[c] * sr[c2] + 1 * sr[c] * sr2[c];
        }
    }

    return -h;
}
```

You will find that without optimizations, this version will run closer to the performance of your array version.

Comment: Hmm you are right - when not using cmake but using clang++ I get: clang++ -std=c++11 vector.cpp -o vector (23 sec), clang++ -std=c++11 array.cpp -o array (6 sec), clang++ -std=c++11 array.cpp -O3 -o arrayO3 (1 sec), clang++ -std=c++11 vector.cpp -O3 -o vectorO3 (1 sec)

Comment: Note, the only modification I made to your code was to make the `h` variable `volatile` so that the loop computation would not get optimized away.

Answer (score 5):

First, you're timing the initialization.  For the array case, there is none (the array is completely uninitialized).  In the vector case, the vector is initialized to zero and then copied into each row.

But the primary reason is cache locality.  The array case is a single block of `50*50` integers which are all continuous in memory, and they can trivially fit in L1D cache.  In the vector case, each row is allocated dynamically which means their addresses are almost certainly not contiguous and are instead spread all over the program's address space.  Accessing one does not pull the adjacent rows into the cache.

Also, because the rows are relatively small, cache space is wasted on adjacent unrelated data, meaning even after you've touched everything to pull it into memory it may not fit in L1 anymore.  And lastly, the access pattern is a lot less linear, and it may be beyond the capability of a hardware prefetcher to predict.

Comment: This seems like a very plausible answer.  Thanks!  Even though the initialization of the vector is slow, I really do not think the initialization is too relevant in this case as it happens once, whereas the loop is iterated 600000 times.

Comment: For this baby problem, I would expect the heap memory for each `vector` to be right next to each other, so cache locality shouldn't be much of an issue. For larger, longer running programs, the point is very valid.

Comment: @pwnell *"I really do not think the initialization is too relevant in this case as [theory]"* -- the theory is not bad, but more convincing would be a trial run where you swapped the lines defining `start` and `sigma_a`...